# Very simple and exact CD burner, with bit-by-bit burning

Tags: optical-media

I need a VERY basic CD burner software. By very basic I mean no encrypting, no verification keys, just simple, exact, bit-by-bit burning. When I tell it to burn a single 1, it does exactly that, nothing else. Is there anything like this? Or is there maybe a way to do it manually by myself?

It would be best if the software could run on Windows 10, directly or with an emulator. And free software would be best.

Comment: Welcome skxy! On which operating system(s) should this software run?  Are you looking for recommendations for gratis software or commercial software, or either?  Please update you question and tags.  Thanks!

Comment: Usually storage devices read/save on a per sector basis or 2k for a CD, so writing a single 1 isn't likely possible without extreme effort.  Writing a single 1 to a sector results in the rest of the sector being 0, and unless your using CD-RW the sector is no longer record able.

Comment: I thought Windows 10 can burn CDs without additional software.

Answer (score 1):

Try an old release of [cdrecord](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html), but it comes with its own build system and was written for Solaris. It is .... controversial in some respects.